# Simple script for scraping data in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

I am planning to build a script for scraping the data from the website which would contain different ids in the url, so I wanna loop through it.

For example, url: http://demosite.com/posts/1
the '1' in the above url will vary from 1 to 2,00,000 in number. So I want to run a python script which would run in a loop and fetch data from the website between those numbers 1-2,00,000.

I am using the following code-

```
import urllib2
import re
for i in xrange(1,200000):
    req = urllib2.Request('http://demosite.com/posts/' + i,
          headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
    html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

    print html
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should show at least minimal effort to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: updated the code which I was using and was facing errors.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is an `int` and `'http://demosite.com/posts/'` is a string. You can't use `+` to concatenate `int` and a string. Either convert `i` to a string (`str(i)`) or use `str.format`:

```
url = 'http://demosite.com/posts/{}'.format(i)
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
```

Comment: what could be the possible way to increase the number of requests to be send in one go and save the output to an txt file?